# Cryptic Crossword Sudoku

Tags: cryptic-clues, sudoku, cryptic-crosswords, grid-deduction

<sub>This puzzle is inspired by Matt’s excellent [Cryptic Sucrosswordoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49401/cryptic-sucrosswordoku).</sub>

Below is a sudoku as well as some cryptic clues. The clues lack enumeration and are in no particular order. The solutions to the clues can be assembled into a path-connected rotationally symmetric crossword inside the sudoku, with each solution beginning in a square whose number is the same as the clue’s enumeration. Given this information, you should be able to deduce the possible enumerations and the form of the crossword itself. Your job is to assemble the crossword atop the sudoku.

[image]

1. Discouraged media forced into action
2. Take over a French square
3. Tree residue after a fire
4. Foolish person captured near canyon
5. Sad strange spots
6. Goes over subpar art and poetry
7. Character at the end finds holes in disorganized site
8. What the despairing cut in impulsive inspiration!
9. Solution lacking wild lions and bird
10. Top dog’s meat placed in empty trophy

Comment: Ooh! This one looks fun.

Comment: Are the clues given in standard crossword ordering? Or do we have to figure that out ourselves?

Comment: @Deusovi, they are not in any kind of order. I numbered them only for convenience (so that people could easily refer to them). You must fit them into the grid yourself.

Comment: @Silenus For future reference, you can order the clues by alphabetical order to hint that order is irrelevant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Part 2: The Cryptics**

Discouraged media forced into action

> DE(PRESS)ED

Take over a French square

> SEIZE (French for 16) *(thanks, Sp3000!)*

Tree residue after a fire

> ASH (ddef)

Foolish person captured near canyon

> A(BY)SS

Sad strange spots

> ADS*

Goes over subpar art and poetry

> (TRA*)VERSES *(thanks, Sp3000!)*

Character at the end finds holes in disorganized site

What the despairing cut in impulsive inspiration!

> _VEINS_ *(thanks, Sp3000!)*

Solution lacking wild lions and bird

> EMU(-lsion) *(thanks, Sp3000!)*

Top dog’s meat placed in empty trophy

> C(-u, +HAM)P *(thanks, Sp3000!)*

**Part 3: The Grid**

I'm fairly sure this is the only grid possible with exactly ten entries without using bars between squares:

> [image]

The final grid is:

> [image]

Comment: fyi explanation for #7 is missing

Answer (score 4):

Part 1: The Sudoku

> [image: sudoku]

And now for the hard part...

Comment: I think we have different opinions about what the "hard part" is... :P